# arangodb 2.0.4 master/slave replication failover procedure needed and HA set

Tags: arangodb

To test the failover scenario and High Availability, I set up master and slave servers, and master now went away (powered down), my thinking is that I could just stop applier in the slave, and start logger in the same slave to promote it to be the new master, and create a new slave to point to the new master by setting up the applier as per the replication manual. Everything will now work as before as long as we switch app to point to the new master for read/write in some way.

If we are using the slave as the standby and only use the master for read/write, this would obviously result in some downtime when we switch to the new master. I also wonder what is the recommended HA setup that will minimize or eliminate downtime, if we use master/slave replication. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you have described is exactly the way how to handle failover. 
Currently the procedure still requires some intervention at the slave and the application, so there might be a short period of unavailability.

We want to improve this in one of the upcoming ArangoDB releases later this year,